# How to abstract a column definition between slick tables?

Tags: scala, generics, slick

I'm trying to add a new column to several tables in an existing slick application. The column is the same across all the tables: adding a client id to the table to enable filtering by client in all our queries. However, in some cases this id will be optional: as such I need to handle both cases using our existing queries.

The problem comes when I try to write some code to use the new column to filter on the new client. I want to write a method to wrap up the table queries for all of the modified tables and optionally filter on client, but slick fails when I try to write a method to do this.

I've tried adding an abstract class extending `Table` in slick to wrap up tables where I want to add the new client column, as such

```scala
  abstract class ClientTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag,name)  {
    def client: Rep[Option[Int]]
  }

  class Feeds(tag: Tag) extends ClientTable[Feed](tag, "feeds") {
    def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

    ...

    def client: Rep[Option[Int]] = column[Option[Int]]("client")

    private val list = id :: name :: ... :: client :: HNil

    def * : ProvenShape[Feed] = list.mappedWith(Generic[Feed])
  }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with slick at all.

Overall, I am hoping to get this method (or something like it) to work:

```scala
  def tableView[T <: ClientTable[E], E] (tableQuery: TableQuery[E], clientId: Option[Int]) = {
    clientId match {
      case Some(id) => tableQuery.filter(_.client === id)
      case None => tableQuery
    }
  }
}
```

so that I can replace the `TableQuery` definition in the queries with `private val xTable = tableView(TableQuery[X], clientId)`, and then hopefully not have to change all my existing queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing worse than an unanswered stack overflow question! As such, here's how I ended up resolving this.

---

The method that I was working towards ended up being correct, I just had my generics slightly wrong. The working version looks like this:

```scala
def tableView[T <: ClientTable[E], E <: ClientColumn](tableQuery: TableQuery[T], clientId: Option[Int]): Query[T, T#TableElementType, Seq] = {
    clientId match {
      case Some(id) => tableQuery.filter(_.client === id)
      case None => tableQuery
    }
  }
```

In the table definitions you need to both extend the `Table` type with an implementation that has the `client` column on it:

```scala
abstract class ClientTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {
  def client: Rep[Option[Int]] = column[Option[Int]]("client")
}
```

and extend your row case classes with a trait that adds the `client` field to all of them as such

```scala
trait ClientColumn {
  def client: Option[Int]
}

case class Feed(id: Int = 0,
                name: String,
...
                client: Option[Int]) extends ClientColumn
```

Now the `tableView` method will work as intended, although seemingly only when passing in type parameters for example `val x = tableView[X, x](TableQuery[X], client)` as Scala doesn't seem to be able to infer the types of both of the generic parameters.

One thing that is worth mentioning is that I am not using Slick for my table creation or ddl statements, I am using flyway instead. Using this method with an `abstract class` and `trait` might not work in that case.

Either way good luck anyone that finds this question and answer in the future!